# Code analysis VB6 Project with CodeSmart via command line?

Tags: vb6, teamcity, static-analysis

I'm using CodeSmart 3.4.6.297 to get code metrics from my vb6 projects.
now i want to include codesmart in my build-process using TeamCity.

I know that codesmart can be user in the command line. this works for me. I have my command line.xml file:

```
<sourcemonitor_commands>
    <write_log>true</write_log>
    <command>
        <project_file>Path to xyz.smproj</project_file>
        <project_language>VB</project_language>
        <modified_complexity>true</modified_complexity>
        <file_extensions>*.cs,*.Designer.cs,*.frm</file_extensions>
        <source_directory>Path to Project</source_directory>
        <include_subdirectories>true</include_subdirectories>
        <checkpoint_name>Baseline</checkpoint_name>
    </command>
</sourcemonitor_commands>
```

which generates a projectXYZ.smproj file.

My question now is...

How do I export data (code metrics like lines of code) from this smproj file using a console command?

i can get code metrics when I open my projectXYZ.smproj file in the codesmart IDE and exporting data using the menue "file...export Checkpoint details" but I need this in a console command

Any ideas?

Greetings
SLimke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an export area to the command block

```
<export>
    <export_file>PathToProject\Checkpoint1.xml</export_file>
   <export_type>2 (checkpoint details as XML)</export_type>
   <export_option>1 (do not use any of the options set in the Options dialog)</export_option>
</export>
```